# Start debugging versus View in browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

What is different between Start debugging and View in browser
I just know that view in browser in faster than Start Debugger but i don't know why.

Comment: Maybe that's because the `View in browser` feature does not launch the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View in browser launches the process of the browser and navigates to your page.

Debug is used when you want to step through your code. Apart from what "view in browser" does, it also attaches the visual studio debugger to the process running asp.net so that they can communicate with each other. It is slower, because visual studio starts tracking the execution of your server code (would it need to hit a breakpoint somewhere).

You can read more on debugging with Visual Studio on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx).